# Speeding Up Script For Google Sheet and Airplane Mode

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, timestamp, google-sheets-api

I have written a simple script for Google Sheet to tally up entries with their timestamp. Right now it takes a couple of seconds for each entry to get registered and I would like to speed it up. Is there an easy way to do that by replacing some steps? I also would like to be able to make this work when one is in airplane mode. With my current script, if I'm offline it stops working until I get out of airplane mode. Is there an easy option somewhere, that allows data entry when in airplane mode? Following is the code. The code gets activated by depressing a button in cell A1, the ballot count appears in cell B1, and in cell C1 there is the timestamp function "=now()"

```
function onOpen() {
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0];
var cell = sheet.getRange("B1");//this is the cell with the current ballot count
var ballot = cell.getValue();// read current ballot count
var timestamp = sheet.getRange('C1').getValue();//read timestamp from cell with formula =now()
sheet.insertRowAfter(2);//add record after separation row, on row 3
cell.setValue(ballot + 1);//
sheet.getRange('a3').setValue(ballot);
sheet.getRange('b3').setValue(timestamp);
}
```

Any idea would be appreciated.

Comment: Run the code, and then from the code editor choose "View" and "Execution Transcript."  That will show you time stamps of when each operation ran.  You should be able to see what is taking the longest time to run.  If you know the name of the first sheet tab, and it will always be the same, then I'd get the sheet by name.  `var sheet = ss.getSheetByName("sheetNameHere");`  Create a timestamp with `var timestamp = new Date();`  That will avoid needing to read cell C1.  I'm wondering if `sheet.insertRowAfter(2)` is what is taking the most time.

Comment: @SandyGood: thanks for the suggestions! It's difficult to tell because time floats around depending also on other background operations. Regardless, the sheet by name  suggestion seems to get the best improvement. The insertRowAfter(2) seemed at first to also be a culprit, but depending on minor variations on the script it was very different from one time to the next. The new Date() was also good.